# Edit Termset using CSV file

Tags: import, term-store, csv

I understand that we can add termset by importing the terms created in CSV file, But i would like to know the possibility to edit(addition of terms) the same CSV file in the future and update the termset in the termstore using that CSV.

Answer (score 1):

you would have to create a custom solution to perform this, possibly through the [Taxonomy Client Service.](http://blogs.solidq.com/sharepoint/Post.aspx?ID=37&title=SharePoint%202010,%20Managed%20Metadata,%20TaxonomyClientService%20in%20depth)